# Why does a user get 'email field required' after submitting a form such as a Contribution page

Tags: drupal, profile, contribution-page, user-account

If a Contribution page has a profile that creates a Drupal User, then the user gets a message after submitting the form that 'email is required' and no Drupal user is created.

Not sure if this is only affecting Drupal.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like to me like this was a problem in 4.7.20 and 4.7.21 and am picking [this JIRA issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15067) is involved and have created [this JIRA issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20834) for the fix.